# REST API in Wordpress for affiliation system

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api

I have a web page with links towards other web pages. Once an user clicks in one of those links, a cookie is created, so in case he makes a purchase in the web page, the info related to this link is sent to us through an "API call".

So far, the code I have used in the following:

```
var storeCookie = getCookie("COOKIE_NAME"); //gets the cookie if it was previously created
if(tiendaCookie!=""){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url="URL TO A .PHP FILE IN MY SERVER";
    peticion.open("POST",url,true);
    peticion.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    peticion.send("PARAMETERS OF THE CALL")
```

The web pages with links on our web page added this code to their web page so the affiliation system can work but we found that when that code is called, the following is returned:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response "URL TO A .PHP FILE IN MY SERVER" with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I know this is not the right way to set up an API endpoint but I have no knowledge about how to proceed. I was going to try this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) but it looks it is not supported in the latest versions of Wordpress.

What would be the right way to do what I am trying?

Thank you.

EDIT

I have done some more research and I have discovered that the problem might be in my .PHP file, because of:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But I have this code on the .PHP file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

What can I be missing?

Comment: When you load the URL in <URL TO A .PHP FILE IN MY SERVER> directly and look at the headers returned by the server, do you see an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Comment: I do not know exactly what you mean. But after adding 
`header('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` I managed to make it work. I did not know that part was mandatory!